# Menu Structure to use esc to return to previous menu

Tags: powershell

I'm practicing writing a menu script to do multiple actions.

```
function createAMenu
{ 
    param([array]$listelements,[string]$title)
        cls
        [int]$counter = 0
        Write-Host "--------",$title,"--------" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        oneEmptyLine
        
        ForEach($element in $listelements)
        {   
            $counter++
            Write-Host "`t", $counter,". ",$element -Separator '' -ForegroundColor White
        }
        oneEmptyLine
        return makeAChoice
}

function oneEmptyLine
{
    Write-Host "`n"
}

function makeAChoice
{
    Write-Host "Write the index of your choice, here: " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
    Try
    {
        [int]$theIndex = Read-Host
    }
    Catch
    {}
    return $theIndex
}

Function pause ($message)
{
    # Check if running Powershell ISE
    if ($psISE)
    {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$message")
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Press Any Key To Continue" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $x = $host.ui.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    }
}
```

Which will call a menu function to create the menu.

```
function mainMenu
{
    
    [array]$theMainMenu = "PC / User Login Tools",`
                          "Active Directory Tools",`
              "PC Setup",`
                          <#"Teams Calling",`#>
                          "Exit"
    [string]$theMenuTitle = "Main Menu"

    Do
    {
        # intager value (index number) to be
        [int]$theChosenIndex = createAMenu $theMainMenu $theMenuTitle
    }
    While($theChosenIndex -lt 1 -or $theChosenIndex -gt $theMainMenu.Count -or !$theChosenIndex)
    cls
    If($theChosenIndex -eq 1)
    {
        UserOptions
    }
    ElseIf($theChosenIndex -eq 2)
    {
        ADOptions
    }
    ElseIf($theChosenIndex -eq 3)
    {
        ComputerSetupOptions
    }
    <#ElseIf($theChosenIndex -eq 4)
    {
        TeamsCalling
    }#>
    Else
    {
        ExitScript
    }

}
```

Im trying to figure out how to add an esc button clause which would be something like:

```
$key = [console]::ReadKey()
if($key.Key -eq '27')
{
     GoToPreviousMenu
}
Else
{
     WhateverOptionWasPushed
}
```

I have tried putting the statement in the makeAChoice function like:

```
Try
{
    $key = [console]::ReadKey()
    if($key.Key -eq '27')
    {
        PreviousMenu
    }
    Else
    {
        [int]$theIndex = Read-Host
    }
    
}
```

But when i do that it will only read the esc key and not the key im trying to return, ie 1,2,3 etc

I know it's probably something simple, but just need an outside set of eyes to see what im overlooking. Thanks in advance and cheers!

Answer (score 0):

- `$key.KeyChar` contains the character that was typed.
- Assuming your menu has at most 9 entries whose indices start with 1, you can use this value instead of prompting with [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host).

  - Note: This means that typing a digit *instantly* makes a selection, instead of requiring a <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress to submit what was typed.

The following shows this technique with a slightly restructured `makeAChoice` function:

- Only characters `1` through `9` are accepted, and returned as the corresponding number (`[int]`)
- Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> causes `0` to be returned.
- Any invalid character triggers a warning and prompts again.

```bash
function makeAChoice
{
    do {
      Write-Host "Write the index of your choice, here: " -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green
      $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true) # $true suppresses echoing the char.
      if ($key.Key -eq 'Escape') {
        Write-Host
        return 0
      }
      elseif ($key.KeyChar -match '[1-9]') {
        Write-Host
        return [int] $key.KeyChar.ToString()
      }
      Write-Warning "`nInvalid choice: '$($key.KeyChar)'. Please try again."
    } while ($true)
}
```

Comment: That works as far as calling the number structure. but gives me an interesting problem. However if i say something like 
If($theChosenIndex -eq 0)
    {
        mainMenu
    }
when the main menu is refreshed (pushing escape) it cause my Menu title to cud off and instead of saying "------- Main Menu -------" it says " ain Menu -------"

Comment: @GlenNewell, replace `$key = [Console]::ReadKey()` with `$key = [Console]::ReadKey($true)` (I've updated the answer too); `$true` suppresses echoing the char., which fixes the problem (though I don't understand why).